# Trouble updating Super Attribute pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product

I'd like to programatically modify this pricing:

[image: Screenshot]

I thought I had something, this updates the attribute price because I can retrieve the new value with `getPrice()`:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'SOME_SKU');
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    $attribute->setPrice(20.00);
    $attribute->save();
    echo $attribute->getPrice(); // 20.00
}
```

However, even after clearing caches and indexes, this value is not reflected in the frontend product configurator, or the admin panel as per the screenshot above.

Is there another method I need to use?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.